# iOS Launch screen not showing image when changing bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, swift, caching, launch-screen, bundle-identifier

I am working on my iOS application and I am facing a problem where I can't see the logo of my application in launch screen when I change the bundle Identifier of my application. When I am using bundle Identifier say `com.demo.app`, launch screen is working fine, but when I change the bundle Identifier for my app to say `com.demo2.app` for release purpose, launch screen image stops working no matter what I do with the image.

So far, I've:

1. Changed the current image with other image to check if the problem resides with the image we are using.
2. Tried dragging the image into the directory instead of using it from Assets folder, and then using the name of that image. What can be the possible problem here?

Comment: Clean the build, deleted the derived data, delete app from device/simulator, then reboot the device or reset settings of the simulator. It's likely to be a cache issue. If your configuration works with a bundle id, it should work with the other one without needing to change the config.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a caching issue, I'd try the following:

1. Remove application from the device
2. Restart device
3. Build again

If that doesn't work, try deleting derived data then cleaning your project. I'd restart Xcode too just to be sure.

`Xcode Preference -> Locationtab -> Derived data` - Then do follow above steps.